# How to get controller/model/store/view in Ajax callback

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, extjs

folks,

I am working on a project using EXTJS MVC framework for backend development.

Now I am in trouble to get controller/model/store in the Ajax callback

Here is the snippet of my code. I am in the controller to call Ajax.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/gdltest/gdl_service.cgi',
    jsonData: jRequest,
    method: 'POST',     
    success: function (response,options) {
        var jsonData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        var jData = jsonData.results.data;
```

When i get the data from the response, I want to get the controller/model/store to do more actions, but i don't know how to get them :(

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

What you've done in the `success` function is correct. Please check the reponse that you're getting back from the server. Also, is the `url` correct? Usually the relative path to the resource is given, not the absolute path, as you've given here. Is the request reaching the server? If it is I think there is an issue with the data which is being sent back. You should also use the `safe` option during development. The safe option throws an error if the Json returned from the server isn't in the proper format. From the docs:

```
decode( String json, [Boolean safe] )
```

> safe : Whether to return null or throw an exception if the JSON is
>   invalid.

**EDIT**: If you want to use the `this` operator inside the success callback then specify the `scope` config. Example below:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/gdltest/gdl_service.cgi',
        jsonData: jRequest,
        method: 'POST',     
        success: function (response,options) {
            var jsonData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            var jData = jsonData.results.data;
       },
       scope : this //this will be the object form which the Ajax.request is called, and not Ajax.request itself or you can specify any other object you desire.
```

Comment: Hi, Varun Achar, I didn't make myself clear. Because I can get the response data correctly. What I am puzzled is how to get controller/model/store inside the callback success function

Comment: I didn't quite understand. What's the problem that you're facing when directly using say `myStore.getCount()` inside the callback? Look's more like a scope issue.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it correctly answers the question.. this brings the question out of the unanswered pool and helps other users.. thanks..